# How to ignore/exclude files from the output of find command using grep?

Tags: bash, grep, find

I am searching for certain files with certain extensions using find command. I would like to use grep command at the end to ignore certain files.

My uncomplete command is:

```
find . -type f \( -name "*.txt" -or -name "*.html" -or -name "*.css" -or -name "*.js" -or -name "*.yml" \) | grep ..
```

Let's say I would like to ignore 2 files: cards.js and radios-and-checkboxes.css

How can I implement that with grep command? I am aware that there are ways without using a grep command but I would like to know how can I do it using grep.

I have looked for different solutions but most of them mentions excluding words or file extensions or using just find command to do a similar task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use grep's -v flag to achieve this. In order to exclude one such item from results:

```
your commands here | grep -v "cards.js"
```

And if you want to chain multiple grep matches, do this:

```
yourcommands here | grep -v -e "cards.js" -e "radios-and-checkboxes.css"`
```

Please use the `-w` if you want EXACT match with the strings in grep. So for an exact match with "cards.js" use: `grep -v -w -e "cards.js"`. Using the `-w` once will work for multiple extends.

Comment: since `.` is used this will match `cardsajs` as well

Comment: @oguzismail as I use find  command to find only .txt, .html, .css, .js and .yml there is no risk for `cardsajs` to be matched as well, is there?

Comment: @Marcin yeah. it will match cardajs.js as well

Comment: see my answer for a safe one

Comment: @oguzismail if I was to use -w with multiple files would the command look like that `grep -v -e -w file1 -e -w file2`?

Comment: @Marcin it wouldn't match filenames containing spaces

Comment: and no, you need to specify -w just once. like `grep -v -w -e file1 -e file2`

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for `grep -v`

```
 $ echo -e "a\nb\nc" | grep -v b
```

This prints everything excluding `b`

Use "-e" to exclude multiple matches,

```
 $ echo -e "a\nb\nc" | grep -v -e a -e b
```

This excludes both `a` and `b`

Answer (score 1):

Use `-E` (extended) and `-v` (invert match) in `grep`:

```
find ... | grep -v -E 'cards\.js|radios-and-checkboxes\.css'
```

The `|` character is the `OR` operator.

Comment: Nice explanation on the flags

Comment: since `.` is used this will match `cardsajs` as well

Answer (score 0):

Pure `find` solution without `grep` :

```
find . -type f \( \( -name "*.txt" -o -name "*.html" -o -name "*.css" -o -name "*.js" -o -name "*.yml" \) -a ! -name "radios-and-checkboxes.css" -a ! -name "cards.js" \)
```

Comment: OP says *I am aware that there are ways without using a grep command but I would like to know how can I do it using grep.*

Comment: Correct, I overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

This script lists files excluding a list of extensions.
It helps when trying to spot garbage files.
Common extensions are used in the example.
It could be more compact, but less readable.

```
#!/bin/bash
EXTENSIONS=$(cat <<'EOE'
.exe
.py
.js
.css
.html
EOE
)                                             # extensions, 1 per line
EXTENSIONS=$(echo "$EXTENSIONS"|tr "\n" "|")  # convert to egrep pattern
EXTENSIONS=${EXTENSIONS%?}                    # remove trailing '|'
find . -type f | egrep -i -v "$EXTENSIONS"    # all files lacking EXTENSIONS
```